# Can you redirect user from Shopify order confirmation page to third party website and pass order details

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have done some research, where I am trying to achieve quite simple thing.
On Shopify order confirmation page display link to allow user to click and visit third party website, ideally link would contain order details as encoded parameters.

Is there simple way how to achieve it? Shopify checkout seems to be quite limited when it comes to customization.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `addition_scripts` in the shopify checkout admin section where you can write custom javascript function. (usually designed for analytics scripts) You can write some custom javascript redirects.

From there you will need to figure out how to pass the order information to the third party site. You can use cookies to save the customer id and request his last order using a Rest API request or some other approach that meets your required output/functionality in the third party site. (how will you secure this I'm not 100% sure)

Please have in mind that you can create a custom App that can hook on the order creation webhook of Shopify and update a database on the third party site.

Once again it really matters what you want to achieve on the 3rd site, but long story short is - Yes, you can redirect from that page using javascript.